# How Do I Build Lua For Windows Using MinGW and MSYS?

Tags: windows, compilation, lua, mingw

I have a book called Beginning Lua Programming which is suppose to go over the raw basics but it is sort of leaving me stranded. Here is an effort to condense 3 pages:

QUOTE:

```
The following environment variables are recommended for Windows:
UTIL_DIR=c:\program files\utility
LUA_DIR=c:\program files\lua\5.1
LUA_CPATH=?.dll;%LUA_DIR%\?.dll
LUA_PATH=?.lua;%LUA_DIR%\?.lua
The UTIL_DIR variable identifies the utility directory you created in the preceding section.
```

After this, there is a segment about setting the 'windows search path' for lua. Basically, it tells me to look up the output of 'doskey /?' and 'path' and figure it out myself. I have no idea what these do, how to use them, and what the difference between them is.

I'm at my wits end. A detailed explanation or a link to a detailed blog/article or youtube video is EXTREMELY appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a few ways to get Lua working on your machine. If you just want to a functional Lua environment in a hurry with minimal fuss then consider downloading one of the precompiled Lua binaries. The common ones being [Lua for Windows](https://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/) and [LuaBinaries](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/).

Building Lua with Mingw isn't too difficult:

- First get your desired Lua version [here](http://www.lua.org/ftp/).
- Extract the tar file containing Lua's source somewhere. For this example, I'll assume you extracted to `c:\lua`
- If you have Msys already set up, you can run the make file from that environment. From the Msys shell, you can build lua with the follow commands:

  ```
  cd /c/lua
  make PLAT=mingw
  make install
  ```
- You should find `lua.exe` and `luac.exe` somewhere in there after the build completes. Lua should be ready for use at this point.

The regular `cmd.exe` shell can work too with some changes to the commands:

```
    cd lua
    mingw32-make PLAT=mingw
```

The `make install` assumes a *nix environment and so doesn't work under a normal windows cmd shell. In this case you can just manually copy the compiled files from `.\lua\src` to where you want or you can just run it directly from there if desired.

Comment: If the OP is a complete newbie this [OS answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280629/c-and-lua-from-usb/18303548#18303548) may be of some help too.

Comment: Nowadays, [lua-users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLua) is really helpful. And if you want to use msvc, this [faq entry](https://www.lua.org/faq.html#1.2) referred to by [this blog](https://wbrawner.com/2023/12/05/compiling-lua-on-windows/#fn:1) will help you. The functions of different source codes can be found [here 'Building Lua on other systems'](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/readme.html#other).