# C++ and Lua from USB

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, lua, usb-drive

So about 2 weeks ago, I started learning C++ and Lua, and I would like to be able to:

1. compile C++ code (it would be a nice bonus if i could have a C compiler as well, as that's next on my list of languages to learn)
2. interpret (is that correct terminology?) Lua, and
3. do all of this from my usb drive WITHOUT downloading anything from the internet or changing the path variable. (I will mostly be working on school computers.)

As a side note, I have fallen in love with Sublime Text 2 (the portable version of which is already on my usb drive). If it's ABSOLUTELY necessary, I'll make do without it, but I would prefer being able to use it wherever I go.

Please be patient with me, as i have mentioned before, I just started learning how to program, and I have little to no knowledge on how things work. **I have seen similar questions, but they never seem to help me much due to my limited knowledge**, so PLEASE don't mercilessly close my question like others I have seen on this site.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any reason you want to learn C++ **before** C?

Comment: Apart from that: it's not easy to have a portable C++ (or C, for that matter). Lua **is** portable, but it was specifically designed with portability in mind anyway.

Comment: @H2CO3 Learning C++ before C is often a very good idea.

Comment: @JohnBandela No, it isn't quite.

Comment: uhh... i didn't mean to start a whole argument by deciding to learn C++ before C, apparently this is a subject on which people get vociferous about?

Comment: @user2533402 you accidentally stepped into an ideological mine field there. A key philosophical point that too many miss is that there is no single correct language to use, and certainly no correct language to learn first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently added [a page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLuaInWindowsForNewbies) on [Lua WIKI](http://lua-users.org/wiki/) (great source of info) that may help you. It is a tutorial for complete newbies on how to build Lua from the sources using only free and "portable" (in the sense of "can be put on usb drives") tools. It is meant for Windows OS users. Do not forget to check the official [getting started](http://www.lua.org/start.html) page and the [main Lua site](http://www.lua.org) as well!

The fact that you cannot download anything is quite restrictive (how could you get a free compiler then?). Anyway as greatwolf mentioned TDM-GCC is a great C/C++ compiler for 32 bit x86 PCs. It is also patched to be perfectly "portable": I usually use it from a portable USB HD. The tutorial I mentioned shows you how to download it and "install it".

Note that although your sysadmin at school may have blocked your ability to change the path variable globally, you can set it for individual processes ("launched programs") using simple batch files (aka Windows command shell scripts).

Create a file named "myshell.cmd" with this content:

```
@set path=%path%;c:\the\path\to\my\app&cmd /K
```

the part `c:\the\path\to\my\app` must be the actual path of the directory (folder) where the application executable is placed. When you double-click on `myshell.cmd` a black box will open (assuming your sysadmin hasn't blocked this feature) where you can invoke the app executables.

For example, if you "installed" the TDM_GCC compiler in `c:\myprogs\GCC` inside that dir you will find a subdir named `bin`. That subdir must be put in the path, so your `myshell.cmd` file will be like this:

```
@set path=%path%;c:\myprogs\GCC\bin&cmd /K
```

Then in the "black box" I mentioned you can invoke the compiler typing:

```
gcc --help
```

As for your learning path, if you intend to learn both Lua and C or C++, I will advice you to try C instead of C++. C++ has more "high-level" features, but it is huge and although Lua can be used embedded in C++ code (of course this is an advanced topic anyway), it is designed to be directly embedded in a C application (it has an API which conforms to C conventions), so for a beginner probably the path Lua --> C --> C+Lua would be a bit easier. C in itself, although difficult to master, is a rather minimalistic language, so the information to digest about it is not that big.

Not to discourage you, but IMO both C and C++ are not the most suitable languages for absolute beginners (they are plenty of pitfalls and have almost no "safety nets" for beginners). But that's up to you, it heavily depends on your skills, dedication and  motivation ;-)

Hope all this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You have been a great help, and I can finally interpret my Lua code at school!

Comment: @user2533402 BTW, just to answer your doubt about terminology: you can simply say "run Lua scripts" ("execute" is also ok) instead of "interpret Lua scripts". Technically speaking you're not wrong (to be precise it is the Lua interpreter that interprets the scripts, though), but saying "I interpret my script" instead of "I run my script" sounds quite funny (and in some contexts it may mislead the person you're speaking with). :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

For windows,

Take a look at

http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

You should be able to extract the download to a usb directory. Then you can click on the .bat file open a command prompt with the correct path settings.

As a bonus, it already includes prebuilt boost, which will make your c++ use easier.

Comment: The school computers all run on 32-bit Windows 7, will that create an issue with the x64-native MinGW distro?

Comment: @user2533402 you want to get a 32bit version of mingw in that case. The 32bit version can run under Win 32-bit or 64-bit but  x64 mingw will only work under Win 64-bit. There are a few build variations out there for mingw. [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) is another one you can check out.

Comment: Will I be able to use TDM-GCC without having to edit the Path variable on the school computers? (Sorry if i sound stupid)

Comment: @user2533402 I haven't looked into sublime too much but I'd imagine you can configure it to invoke mingw compiler from a path relative to sublime's location. That should allow you to build from sublime without mucking around with the environment path.

Comment: nuwen package has a couple of helpful batch files to set the environment correctly

Answer (score 1):

For the C/C++ piece would also recommend you start with C. Not for ideological reasons, just that it's a lot simpler if you're trying to work out the basics of compiling/linking etc.

As a first C compiler I would recommend the tiny C compiler

[Tiny C Compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/)

It's one of the simplest to get your head around that I've seen and you can still build lua libraries etc.

Once you're comfortable with that then progressing to one of the more powerful environments such as gcc under MingW or Visual C++ should be a bit less daunting.

Answer (score 0):

Lua is trivial. Download the binaries, put them on your drive, and configure Sublime Text to invoke them on Lua files.

C/C++ is more complicated only because of the range of options is so vast. I use a 2003 version of Microsoft Visual C++, which covers my needs. I find a copy [here](http://uploading.com/files/thankyou/HNH73WB3/VCToolkitSetup%28v1.01%29%282004.07.06%29.zip?).

Keep in mind that C++ is a vastly more complicated superset (non-strict) of C, so you're going to learn most of C in the process of learning C++. IMO, learning C first is better for a whole host of reasons. You'll hear some people argue the opposite, but in this case there's a clincher: Lua is written in C and its API is designed for C. Exposing idiomatic C++ (i.e. objects) to Lua is a big ball of complexity that you just don't need right now, while learning two languages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But can you clear some things up for me?
1. I don't know what you mean by "lua binaries", can i just put LuaforWindows on my drive?
2. How do i configure Sublime Text Portable so that it'll work? (Sorry if i sound like a complete idiot, i need to be walked through most stuff step-by-step)

Comment: "Lua binaries" is in contrast to "Lua source"; meaning a built version of the source, for some platform. LuaForWindows is a massive installation, including tons of crap you don't need. You just need a build of the Lua interpreter for Windows. The Lua [download page](http://www.lua.org/download.html) links to binaries for every platform, [including Windows](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html). Grab win32 or win64, extract to your drive, and you're done. As for configuring your editor to run the interpreter, RTM. This is *very* basic editor usage that you need to learn how to do.

Comment: OK, thanks for all of your help! Now i shall go and RTM :)

Comment: The advantage that Lua for Windows has over the LuaBinaries distribution is that big pile of pre-built modules. This was in response to direct requests from the Lua user community for a distribution that would just work out of the box and include "interesting" and "useful" modules that are otherwise difficult for new users to correctly build and configure. It isn't the only way to get started, but it is IMHO a good way. If you don't need features outside of the console and basic modules, and want to learn to build modules from source, then start with LuaBinaries.