# Windows Lua to executable

Tags: c, windows, compilation, lua, executable

hi I have a Lua program (written in Lua 5.1). I'm on Windows 7, trying to convert it to an executable. No luck so far. I've read other posts here that suggested using srlua to do this so I've downloaded it but I'm on a loss as to what to do next. I installed cygwin as I understand it's necessary but I don't know how to use srlua to convert a lua file into an executable. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can easily make stand-alone exe-file from bunch of your lua.exe+lua.dll+script.lua+runme.bat files using ThinApp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

srlua is distributed as source only, so you have to compile it first (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280629/c-and-lua-from-usb/18303548#18303548) for suggestions on getting a free C compiler).

BTW, Cygwin is not necessary at all. The aforementioned link will lead you to instructions to install TDM-GCC, a Windows port of GCC compiler that will create executable files which only depend on Windows default system libraries.

Once you have a C compiler in place and you have compiled srlua, you will have two executable files `glue.exe` and `srlua.exe`. This latter is only a stub, used by `srlua.exe` to generate the final executable by joining it with your Lua script.

Assuming your script is `myscript.lua` and you want to create an executable named `myexe.exe` you must invoke `glue.exe` from the command line as follows:

```
 glue.exe srlua.exe myscript.lua myexe.exe
```

I assumed that all the relevant files are placed in the same directory and you changed to that directory from the command line.

**Addendum:** I just double checked the official download page for [srlua](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/) and I saw there is also a package with already compiled binaries for Windows. So you could skip all the compilation from source part and simply download and unpack [this](http://www.soongsoft.com/lhf/lua/5.1/srlua.tgz).

The binaries are in the `Release` subdirectory inside the archive. Note that these are for Lua 5.1 only, so if your script uses features of Lua 5.2 you must follow my initial advice and compile from source.

Comment: Thanks it worked great. What I don't understand though is this: I've got several functions in my lua file so how do I specify which one should be executed? In java or C we have a main function and that executes but what about lua file containing only functions?

Comment: The script is executed from the first line. Technically the script itself is the body of a Lua function, and that function is what is executed by the interpreter when you run the script. In other languages you could call it an "anonymous" function, but in Lua it would be misleading terminology because functions technically have no name (only variables have), since they are (first-class) values. What you see as function names are indeed variables (locals, globals or table fields) having functions as value. BTW note that in Lua you can define new functions inside other functions.

Answer (score 0):

As for now. These works. Compile or Pack build.

- [luastatic](https://github.com/ers35/luastatic)
  Lua script to executable compiler.
- [dogfood](https://github.com/PG1003/dogfood)
  A tool for building self contained Lua executables