# cygwin on win7, ctrl-d doesn't have effect

Tags: c, keyboard, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin to compile C programs from the book Head First C. On my Win 7 laptop, when I enter text that the program is supposed to process, the book says to end the list of strings with Ctrl-d. Well, nothing happens. If I hit Ctrl-c, Cygwin closes. I heard to use Ctrl-Z instead but that will print "Stopped."

I tried adding a line that replaces \n with \0 because that was the answer to a problem that was on the errata.

How do I show the program that I'm done entering text? I see a lot of questions about Ctrl-C or if they ask about Ctrl-D they want to end the program. I want to keep the program running and just end the input.

Cygwin mintty 1.2-beta1

Here's the 3 files; the exercise is about making your own header files.

message_hider.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "encrypt.h"

int main() {

    char msg[80];
    while(fgets(msg, 80, stdin)) {
        if(msg[strlen(msg)-1] == '\n')
            msg[strlen(msg)-1] = '\0';
        encrypt(msg);
        printf("%s", msg);
    }
}
```

encrypt.c

```
#include "encrypt.h"


void encrypt(char * message) {

    char c;
    while (*message) {
        *message = *message ^ 31;
        message++;
    }
}
```

encrypt.h

```
void encrypt(char * message);
```

Comment: Ctrl-Z should be right.

Comment: Are you entering ctrl-d on a line by itself?

Comment: Ctrl-Z stops the program. That's not what I want to do. I enter ctrl-d on a line by itself.

Comment: Well, you don't have anything after the input loop in the program, so there's nothing else to do.

Comment: OK I see that now, because I entered it in a unix machine and i saw it working properly, so maybe the problem is not the ctrl-d. because when I run this in cygwin, the encryption does not immediately spit out after each line as it should. I was thinking it would wait till all the text was entered to spit out the encryption. Now I see it's not showing the encryption when it should, so it must not be seeing the end of each line I input, despite my substitution.

Comment: Put this statement `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` just after the opening brace of your `main`. This turns out buffering for `stdout`, so you should see your output as soon as it is produced. Maybe it helps you diagnose the problem.

Comment: That worked! I also saw that I need to add a \n after the encryption prints out ... thank you! I can't vote for this as an answer tho. Can you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following statement:

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

just after the opening brace of your `main` function.

This turns out buffering for `stdout`. In this way you should see your output as soon as it is produced and it may help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're stuck with Cygwin for some reason. Since it seems that you are just learning C, maybe you could use a compiler that has native support for Windows, instead of relying on an intermediate layer as Cygwin.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340421/windows-lua-to-executable/18340742#18340742) for how to get up and running with TDM-GCC on Windows (a port of GCC).

BTW, on Windows `CTRL-Z` is the correct way to insert an `EOF` (signaling end of input) in a console.

Comment: I have access to a remote linux account but it's a little less convenient for certain things. But this is getting really annoying.

I have Visual Studio but most of the book is geared toward Linux/Unix.

Comment: @punstress Ok. No, then, TDM-GCC won't help you with all *nix related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question of the proper coding method.  Control-D in fact doesn't work as an input factor over Remote Desktop or Cygwin minitty. I have the same issue, and trying to find a solution.

Control-C and Control-F/Control-B in vi are working ok. So I am assuming Control-D is being intercepted for Windows keystroke reasons which is a "Duplicate" function.