# Easiest way to compile a lua script (*.exe)...?

Tags: compilation, lua, exe

I just made a small program and I'd like to share it with my friends and family.

Which is the best, the fastest and the easiest way to compile a Lua script?

I'm working on Windows, so I would need a *.exe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340421/windows-lua-to-executable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to turn your Lua script into a .exe, try [srlua](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/%7Elhf/ftp/lua/#srlua).

Comment: Ok, is there any manual to use it?

Btw, thank you for the answer! :)

Comment: @MatteoBini, the README is available at https://github.com/LuaDist/srlua/blob/master/README.md. BTW, [LuaDist](http://luadist.org) may have a precompiled binary ready to use.

Comment: @MatteoBini, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340421/windows-lua-to-executable.