# compiling .lua to exe

Tags: lua, exe

I'm trying to compile my script`
loops= 100

function OnEvent(event, arg)

if keypress(0x61) then

x1, y1 = GetMousePosition()

end

```
if keypress(0x62) then
    i = 0

    while (i<loops) do
        if IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
        i = loops
        end
        ReleaseKey("lshift")

        if not IsModifierPressed("lshift") then

            i=i+1
        move1 = math.random(1300,1400)
        move2 = math.random(1300,1400)
        move3 = math.random(1300,1400)
        MoveMouseTo(x1,y1)
        Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        PressMouseButton(3)
        Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        ReleaseMouseButton(3)
        Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        x1 = x1+move1
        MoveMouseTo(x1,y1)
            Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        PressMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(math.random(75,100))
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
            Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        if IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
        i = loops
        end
        ReleaseKey("lshift")

        MoveMouseTo(x1,y1)
        Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        PressMouseButton(3)
        Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        ReleaseMouseButton(3)
        Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        x1 = x1+move2
        MoveMouseTo(x1,y1)
            Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        PressMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(math.random(75,100))
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
            Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        if IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
        i = loops
        end
        ReleaseKey("lshift")

        MoveMouseTo(x1,y1)
        Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        PressMouseButton(3)
        Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        ReleaseMouseButton(3)
        Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        x1 = x1+move3
        MoveMouseTo(x1,y1)
            Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        PressMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(math.random(75,100))
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
            Sleep(math.random(75,100))
        if IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
        i = loops
        end
        ReleaseKey("lshift")

        x1 = x1-move1-move2-move3
    end
end
        MoveMouseTo(x1,y1)
        Sleep(math.random(50,75))
        PressMouseButton(3)
        Sleep(math.random(50,75))
        ReleaseMouseButton(3)
        Sleep(math.random(50,75))
        x1 = x1+move1
        MoveMouseTo(x1,y1)
        Sleep(math.random(50,75))
        PressMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(math.random(50,75))
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
        x1 = x1-move1
```

end
end`
into a .exe using free pascal compiler, every time i run the compiler i get the error (1,6) Fatal: Syntax error, "BEGIN" expected but "identifier LOOPS" found
Fatal: Compilation aborted, I'm fairly new to programming, and im wondering what went wrong

Comment: Each language, and even each particular variant of a language, requires its own specific compiler or interpreter.  You can not mix languages and compilers and expect any meaningful results.  So, a Pascal compiler cannot compile Lua programs just as much as a Lua interpreter can not run a Pascal program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to compile a Lua script using free pascal compiler, which is unlikely to work. You may want to check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897314/easiest-way-to-compile-a-lua-script-exe) for information on how to compile a lua script to an executable.