# How to make a lua file?

Tags: lua, exe

I wanna try to make a ".exe" file using lua code.
I've tried lua.org but i don't understand anything about it.
i've followed tutorials but they all don't help.

It would help me alot if there was a setup file that does all the setup and
lets me able to make .lua files.

Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897314/easiest-way-to-compile-a-lua-script-exe

Comment: Also have a look at: https://love2d.org/wiki/Game_Distribution - LÖVE using Lua 5.1 for coding.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in to Lua that will let you do this, so you need to either write some C code yourself or use a third-party tool. If you want to go the third-party route, https://github.com/PG1003/dogfood is an example of such a tool.