# Build Lua 5.2.2 in Windows

Tags: windows, build, lua, lua-5.2

I already have [Lua For Windows](https://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/) installed but as I read about the latest version of Lua which is **5.2.2**, I noticed that [Lua For Windows](https://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/) is using an old version of Lua which is 5.1.

I want to build the latest lua version to my windows 7 pc, but I don't quite get the idea on how I can build it. I already read this too [Detailed Instruction for installing Lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/readme.html). Do i need to remove the [Lua For Windows](https://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/) ? please give me links how I can build it? what are the necessary tools to build the last lua source code.

**Note**: please also tell how can I test a source on it.

Comment: you might find [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641826/how-do-i-build-lua-for-windows-using-mingw-and-msys/16642434#16642434) helpful if you're looking to build lua from source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua binaries are hosted on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/). You don't need to remove Lua for Windows. What I do on my installation of LFW is, I overwrite the `lua.exe` and `lua.dll` with the respective **5.2.*** files from the binaries I downloaded.

PS: Sourceforge hasn't been updated with 5.2.2 release of Lua and is still at [version 5.2.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.2.1/Executables/). If you want to build, you'll find the similar question that [greatwolf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063139/build-lua-5-2-2-in-windows#comment28177840_19063139) has [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641826/how-do-i-build-lua-for-windows-using-mingw-and-msys).

Answer (score 5):

Compiling lua on Windows using Visual Studio is as simple as:

1. Downloading a copy of the lua source code and extracting it
2. Opening a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt and navigating to the 'src' directory
3. Run this command: `move luac.c .. & cl *.c -o lua.exe /O1`

Comment: It appears that you need to exclude `onelua.c` (assuming that this is the new name for `luac.c`).